# Same-color arithmetic progressions

Tags: code-golf, math, sequence, combinatorics, subsequence

[Van der Waerden's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_der_Waerden%27s_theorem) says that

> For any given positive integers `r` and `k`, there is some number `N` such
>   that if the integers `{1, 2, ..., N}` are colored, each with one of `r`
>   different colors, then there are at least `k` integers in arithmetic
>   progression all of the same color. The least such `N` is the Van der
>   Waerden number `W(r, k)`.

Your goal is to compute the Van der Waerden number `W(r, k)` given positive-integer inputs `r` and `k`. Fewest bytes wins.

Beware that this function grows [extremely quickly](https://wwwold.cs.umd.edu/~gasarch/TOPICS/vdw/gowers-sz-4AP.pdf) and is time-consuming to compute. Even `W(4, 4)` is unknown. You may assume your code runs on an ideal computer with unlimited resources (time, memory, stack depth, etc). Your code must theoretically give the right answer even for values for which the answer is not known.

Built-ins that compute this function are not allowed.

**Example**

For `r = 2` colors and progressions of length `k = 3`, there is a length-`8` sequence that avoids such a progression, i.e. `3` equally-spaced elements of the same color:

```
B R R B B R R B
```

But, there's no such length-`9` sequence, so `W(2, 3) == 9`. For instance,

```
R B B R B R R B R
  ^     ^     ^
```

contains the length-`3` same-color arithmetic progression shown.

**Test cases**

You'll probably only be able to test small cases.

```
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+------+
|     | k=1 | k=2 | k=3 | k=4 | k=5 | k=6  |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+------+
| r=1 |   1 |   2 |   3 |   4 |   5 |    6 |
| r=2 |   1 |   3 |   9 |  35 | 178 | 1132 |
| r=3 |   1 |   4 |  27 | 293 |     |      |
| r=4 |   1 |   5 |  76 |     |     |      |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+------+
```

```js
var QUESTION_ID=71776,OVERRIDE_USER=20260;function answersUrl(e){return"https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/71776/answers?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+ANSWER_FILTER}function commentUrl(e,s){return"https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/"+s.join(";")+"/comments?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+COMMENT_FILTER}function getAnswers(){jQuery.ajax({url:answersUrl(answer_page++),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){answers.push.apply(answers,e.items),answers_hash=[],answer_ids=[],e.items.forEach(function(e){e.comments=[];var s=+e.share_link.match(/\d+/);answer_ids.push(s),answers_hash[s]=e}),e.has_more||(more_answers=!1),comment_page=1,getComments()}})}function getComments(){jQuery.ajax({url:commentUrl(comment_page++,answer_ids),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){e.items.forEach(function(e){e.owner.user_id===OVERRIDE_USER&&answers_hash[e.post_id].comments.push(e)}),e.has_more?getComments():more_answers?getAnswers():process()}})}function getAuthorName(e){return e.owner.display_name}function process(){var e=[];answers.forEach(function(s){var r=s.body;s.comments.forEach(function(e){OVERRIDE_REG.test(e.body)&&(r="<h1>"+e.body.replace(OVERRIDE_REG,"")+"</h1>")});var a=r.match(SCORE_REG);a&&e.push({user:getAuthorName(s),size:+a[2],language:a[1],link:s.share_link})}),e.sort(function(e,s){var r=e.size,a=s.size;return r-a});var s={},r=1,a=null,n=1;e.forEach(function(e){e.size!=a&&(n=r),a=e.size,++r;var t=jQuery("#answer-template").html();t=t.replace("{{PLACE}}",n+".").replace("{{NAME}}",e.user).replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",e.language).replace("{{SIZE}}",e.size).replace("{{LINK}}",e.link),t=jQuery(t),jQuery("#answers").append(t);var o=e.language;/<a/.test(o)&&(o=jQuery(o).text()),s[o]=s[o]||{lang:e.language,user:e.user,size:e.size,link:e.link}});var t=[];for(var o in s)s.hasOwnProperty(o)&&t.push(s[o]);t.sort(function(e,s){return e.lang>s.lang?1:e.lang<s.lang?-1:0});for(var c=0;c<t.length;++c){var i=jQuery("#language-template").html(),o=t[c];i=i.replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",o.lang).replace("{{NAME}}",o.user).replace("{{SIZE}}",o.size).replace("{{LINK}}",o.link),i=jQuery(i),jQuery("#languages").append(i)}}var ANSWER_FILTER="!t)IWYnsLAZle2tQ3KqrVveCRJfxcRLe",COMMENT_FILTER="!)Q2B_A2kjfAiU78X(md6BoYk",answers=[],answers_hash,answer_ids,answer_page=1,more_answers=!0,comment_page;getAnswers();var SCORE_REG=/<h\d>\s*([^\n,]*[^\s,]),.*?(\d+)(?=[^\n\d<>]*(?:<(?:s>[^\n<>]*<\/s>|[^\n<>]+>)[^\n\d<>]*)*<\/h\d>)/,OVERRIDE_REG=/^Override\s*header:\s*/i;
```

```css
body{text-align:left!important}#answer-list,#language-list{padding:10px;width:290px;float:left}table thead{font-weight:700}table td{padding:5px}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/codegolf/all.css?v=83c949450c8b"> <div id="answer-list"> <h2>Leaderboard</h2> <table class="answer-list"> <thead> <tr><td></td><td>Author</td><td>Language</td><td>Size</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="answers"> </tbody> </table> </div><div id="language-list"> <h2>Winners by Language</h2> <table class="language-list"> <thead> <tr><td>Language</td><td>User</td><td>Score</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="languages"> </tbody> </table> </div><table style="display: none"> <tbody id="answer-template"> <tr><td>{{PLACE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr></tbody> </table> <table style="display: none"> <tbody id="language-template"> <tr><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr></tbody> </table>
```

Answer (score 8):

### Python 3.5, <s>125</s> <s>124</s> 119 bytes

```py
f=lambda r,k,*L:any(L[:x*k:x]==k*(*{*L[:x*k:x]},)for x in range(1,len(L)+1))*len(L)or max(f(r,k,i,*L)for i in range(r))
```

It's funny because, over the course of golfing this, the program actually got *more* efficient. Anything beyond `f(2,4)` or `f(3,3)` still takes forever, though.

#### Explanation

The initial version checked whether a sequence contained a progression of length `k` by trying all possible start indices and steps.

```py
def f(r,k,L=[]):
 for i in range(len(L)):
  for j in range(len(L)):
   if len(set(L[i::j+1]))==1 and len(L[i::j+1])==k:
    return len(L)
 return max(f(r,k,L+[i])for i in range(r))
```

The golfed version only needs to try all possible steps since it *prepends* new sequence elements. The `x*k` cap is to take care of cases like `[0, 0, 1]`, which contains a progression of length 2 but would not satisfy the uniqueness check uncapped.

As for the check

```py
L[:x*k:x]==k*(*{*L[:x*k:x]},)
```

On the first pass of the golfed version, when `L` is empty, `len(L)` is 0. Thus the second half of the `or` will always be executed. After that `L` is non-empty, so `{*L[:x*k:x]}` (which is just Python 3.5 for `set(L[:x*k:x])`) will have at least one element.

Since `L[:x*k:x]` can have at most `k` elements and for `L` non-empty `k*(*{*L[:x*k:x]},)` has at least `k` elements, the two can only be equal when there are exactly `k` elements in both. For this to happen `{*L[:x*k:x]}` must have exactly one element, i.e. we only have one colour in our progression.